# Can I generate the code behind for a Specflow/CodedUI solution with MSBuild?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, specflow

We had to upgrade our Visual Studio versions to 2017 and as far as I can tell from looking at this thread: [New CSProj files causing issues with Specflow code-behind generation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/820) you can generate the code behind using an MSBuild workaround. My question is can I replicate the CodedUI plugin you need to make CodedUI work with Specflow using this workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find documentation for the manual process here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/

In SpecFlow 2.3 we added a NuGet package to automate most of it. It's called SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.
 Please use at least the version 2.3.2-preview20180328. The versions before had a bug in the MSBuild files, which is fixed in this version.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation/2.3.2-preview20180328